# tkinter won't quit when I press quit button, it just changes location

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code and when I run it the quit button doesn't work:

```py
def quit2():

    menu.destroy()
def menu1():

    menu=Tk()
    global menu
    play=Button(menu, text='play', command =main)
    play.pack()
    quit1=Button(menu, text='quit', command=quit2)
    quit1.pack()
    menu.mainloop()

while True:

    menu1()
```

Comment: You explicitly recreate the gui in an infinite loop. Why do you expect anything different?

Answer (score 1):

You use `while True` so after you close window `while True` opens new window.

Use last line `menu1()` without `while True`

**EDIT:**

```
from tkinter import *

def quit2():
    menu.destroy()

def menu1():
    global menu

    menu = Tk()

    play = Button(menu, text='play', command=main)
    play.pack()
    quit1 = Button(menu, text='quit', command=quit2)
    quit1.pack()

    menu.mainloop()

#without `while True`
menu1()
```

Comment: its doesnt do anything know @furas

Comment: Your `quit` button works but `while True: menu1()` open your program again and again, and it looks like `quit` doesn't work. I add code to answer

Comment: this is my whole code pls check as it still crashes could i send u an email @furas

Comment: My example works for me. If some code gives error message the always send full error message.

Comment: BTW. if you use Python2 then you have to use upper `T` in word `tkinter``.

Comment: maybe put code on pastebin.com (or similar) and send link

Comment: I see two problems. First: you have to use `gobal variable` before `variable = value` so better put all `global`s at the beginning of function. Second: someone can write text ie. "hello" (or keep empty field) and you try to convert  it to integer and you get error - you need `try/except` to catch error and do something with this - ie. display some message in Labe()/Text()/Message() or Standard Dialog http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm . If you have more question - my email: furas@tlen.pl

Comment: ps. and code formatting is a problem. we all use (almost) the same rules to format code so we can easily read other people code. for example 'one space' after ',' and around '=' (but not around `=' inside '()' ), 'long_names' with '_' between words.

Comment: In your pastebin code you call `Tk()` twice. That won't work like you expect. Tkinter needs exactly one root window, not two.

Comment: @BryanOakley I found `menu.destroy()` (in two places). Shouldn't it destroy first root window before OP creates new one ?